# creating columns using sum of existing column and looping

Tags: python, pandas, calculated-columns

I am trying to generate new columns using the existing columns in the data frame. My dataframe has 60 columns . To need to generate 60 new columns based on the data in the data frame. These columns should only contain the sum.
E.g

```
Index column_a column_b month 
0.         1.     3.     Jan 
1.         2.     4.     Feb
2.         3.     4      Match
```

```
Index column_a column_b month  sum_a sum_b
0.         1       2.    Jan.   6.      10
1.         2.      4.    Feb.   6.      10
2.         3.      4     Match. 6.      10
```

Keep in mind that I need to iterate this for 60 columns. Would appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: `sum_b` should be 11 i think? not `10`

Answer (score 2):

first create the list of columns on which you have to calculate sum then iterate on those columns

```
list_of_cols =['col_a','col_b']
for i in list_of_cols:
    name = 'sum_'+ i
    df[name] = df[i].sum()
```

I hope it would solve your problem

Comment: This one is giving a syntax error.  return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))

Comment: Thanks, resolved the issues, the headers were the class float, changing it into string helped.

Comment: @Crunchnumbers approve or upvote thr answer so that more people can benefit from this.